# Get text from pdf document using script

Tags: windows, linux, bash

How to get text from pdf document using script? I use windows and occasionally linux.

Comment: This doesn't show much effort of googling, so I'll just throw TIKA in here (http://tika.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `pdftohtml` available on most Linux distributions. As the name implies, it can convert PDF to HTML. Converting HTML to plain text can be accomplished in many ways, for example using `lynx -dump file.html`

Comment: Thanks. But the tool can not copy text if the document has disabled coping of text... I have really long document which I want read in voice reader.

Answer (score 1):

You can use on Linux [pdftotext](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_pdftote.htm) command (part of [poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/)).

Comment: Thanks. But the tool can not copy text if the document has disabled coping of text or if it includes password?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't try it with textcopy-disabled pdf. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to use your mouse to grab text from a PDF, you should run `xpdf`.  It doesn’t seem to pay attention to security settings. At least, the version I run on my Mac doesn’t.